# WinRT, Javascript and the random "Access denied" exception

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

### Some background

During last days I've been developing some Windows 8 HTML5/WinJS application. This application does some job using a WinRT component.

The JavaScript part starts an asynchronous operation in collaboration with the whole WinRT component: the callback function is given by JavaScript and the WinRT calls it when it has some asynchronous result.

I forgot to mention that the whole Windows 8 application isn't developed using the *single page approach*.

### Problem

If the whole asynchronous operation is called in some page and you don't navigate to other pages, everything works as expected.

But, *what happens when you navigate to other page?* When the WinRT component needs to notify the JavaScript part about the result of the asynchronous operation: **ACCESS DENIED EXCEPTION**! And your application crashes.

### What I've tried so far

- The whole WinRT component method returns an `IAsyncOperation<T>`: before navigating to other page, I call the `.cancel()` method in JavaScript => **NO LUCK**
- I've put the callback function into `WinJS.Application.sessionState` in order to be sure that the whole function isn't destroyed by the garbage collector => **NO LUCK**

### The question...

**Do I have any chance to notify the WinRT component to cancel it's asynhcronous operation and don't try to return the control to the JavaScript callback?**

*Thanks in advance*

*You can check that others have found the same problem before:*

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/5f9ebfe6-d652-442d-850d-41bda5e370c9

Comment: @markp3rry It's because this is a tech demo and it really have a single page. But I need to open some external web page and I did it in another app page with just an iframe and the back button to the main menu. I thought the effort of creating a true navigation doesn't justify using it in this small project...

Comment: Sorry... that was a bit of a stupid comment (I deleted it but you beat me to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution after some trial-errors.

Answering to my own question:

> Do I have any chance to notify the WinRT component to cancel it's
>   asynhcronous operation and don't try to return the control to the
>   JavaScript callback?

Yes, but *not directly*.

So, how?

1. In the WinRT, C# component-side, design a `CancellationTokenSource` property in the C# WinRT component and, assign it just before the call to the asynchronous operation.
2. Create an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` and set it to the property created in the previous step just before calling the asynchronous operation.
3. Fluently-continue with `ContinueWith` method the asynchronous operation before converting the .NET Task into a WinRT `IAsyncOperation<T>` and give the `CancellationToken` created as part of the previously instantiated `CancellationTokenSource` to the `ContinueWith` method (see cancelling tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).
4. Implement a `CancelCurrentAsyncOperation` method in the WinRT component that will call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`.
5. Call the previously `CancelCurrentAsyncOperation` method in WinJS/JavaScript before navigating to another page.

#### WinRT component sample code:

```
public sealed class MyWinRTComponent 
{
   private CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

   public void CancelLastAsyncOperation() 
   {
       if(CancellationTokenSource != null) 
       {
           CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
       }
   }

   public IAsyncOperation<string> DoSomethingAsync() 
   {
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        return DoSomethingAsync()
                     .ContinueWith<string>(task => task.Result, CancellationTokenSource);
   }
}
```

#### JavaScript sample code:

```
var component = new MyWinRTComponent();
component.doSomethingAsync().then(function(text) {
   // Do stuff
});

// Before navigating to other page
component.cancelCurrentAsyncOperation();
```

That worked for me!!